# Unable to create 'launch.json' file inside the '.vscode' folder (Cannot read property 'length' of undefined)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

After installing C/C++ extension from Microsoft on my Win32 PC, when I want to debug my code, occurs sth like that:

```
Unable to create 'launch.json' file inside the '.vscode' folder (Cannot read property 'length' of undefined).
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: In the same directory as your project, create a directory named `.vscode` if it does not already exist. After doing that, read this article: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md.

Answer (score 0):

- Create the .vscode manually,
- then re-start vscode,
- then let the c/c++ extension to create the laungh.json.